# (How) can I make a request for movie recommendations on topic?

Tags: discussion

Is this a question for meta, rather than the main site, or would it be on topic there?

I was thinking of asking on [the SO movies site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), first on meta, if it woule be on topic there, but I think that there would be more expertise here.

I am looking for some movies, or docuemntaries,  which are as historically accurate as can be with regard to the Roman legions, preferably from the time of Marius to August, but I will take what I can get. I say movies, rather than docuemntaries, as documentaries tend to show a professor standing in front of some ruins, narrating, and I want actual "legion-like" video (plot is somwaht secondary).

I *feel* like asking this on the main site would sully it, but would it be ok to ask here?

It is easy enough to search for movies which feature the legions, but I am looking for something which is historically accurate, as opposed to Hollywood glitz.

Comment: Movie *recommendations* are off-topic on Movies:SE

Comment: I imaginwd so, and would not sink to "what was they name of that extremely historically accurate movie about the legions.. ?", which would be on topic. If char here won't do it, I will find a non-SO site - if I can remember how :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that asking for movie *recommendations* is considered to be off-topic on Movies:SE.

If you check the [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), asking for reference material is also off-topic on History:SE.  Personally, I'd assume that included requests for movies/documentaries.

The best place to ask your question is probably in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine).

Comment: I suspected as much. I will try chat. If that doesn't help, I will look elsewhere. Thanks